# IEnumerable<> Returns object reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: c#, ienumerable, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to get a value from an Interface. I have a function like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Car> CreateCars()
{
    IEnumerable<Car> carList = new List<Car>()
    {
        new Car{ Id = 1, Name = "Opel", CarProperties = { Color= "White", Model= "2012" }},
        new Car{ Id = 2, Name = "Citroen", CarProperties = { Color= "Blue", Model = "2014" }},
        new Car{ Id = 6, Name = "Peugeot", CarProperties = { Color= "Red", Model = "2013" } }
    };

    return carList;
}
```

When I call the method it gives exception:

> object reference not set to instance of an object.

I searched but could not find an answer. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What is a type of CarProperties ?

Comment: you need to set new { Color="White"....

Comment: Your code does not throw a null reference exception so - I suggest you use a debugger for 30 seconds and find out where the error actually is.

Comment: @TomTom How do you know it does not throw a null reference exception?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. Giving CarPropeties a type solve the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the exception is raised here:

```
new Car{ Id = 1, Name = "Opel", CarProperties = { Color= "White", Model= "2012" }},
```

You should initialize `CarProperties` with its corresponding type. Something like:

```
new Car { Id = 1, Name = "Opel", CarProperties = new CarProperty { Color= "White", Model= "2012" } },
```

You can also initialize the `CarProperties` property in the constructor of the `Car` class.

Comment: I think *You should initialize `CarProperties` with its corresponding type* doesn't make much sense. How about *You should initialize `CarProperties` by creating a new instance of `CarProperty`*, which is what your code actually does?

Answer (score 4):

```
new Car{ Id = 1, Name = "Opel", CarProperties = { Color= "White", Model= "2012" }}
```

This line is equivalent to this:

```
car = new Car();
car.Id = ...
car.Name = ...
car.CarProperties.Color = ...
```

The fact that you're getting a `NullReferenceException` leads me to believe `car.CarProperties` is null.

One possible fix is to change the `Car` constructor to initialize the `CarProperties` property or its backing field.

```
public class Car
{
    public SomeType CarProperties {get; private set;}

    public Car()
    {
        CarProperties = new SomeType();
    }    
}
```